# RUBY : selenium webdriver alert is not working

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Ho to detect an alert and accept it, let say we open this site  http://www.boloco.com/" and we want to detect the alert popup and click on the button , I used

```
driver.switch_to.alert.accept
```

But it said no dialog box.

UPDATE :

Since I popup in this web site does not exist anymore, in our production code we have a dialog that pop up, I search in the source code , I found the dialog box code like this :

```
    <div class="roster-alert modal fade" id="roster-alert" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="OKAY, GOT IT"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h2>Any recent employee changes?</h2>
        <p class="content">Looks like it&#39;s been awhile since you last visited. Please take a quick moment to review your staff roster and update any changes.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary roster-alert-cta" data-dismiss="modal">OKAY, GOT IT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, the pop up is not Java Script alert so you can't use

```
driver.switch_to.alert.accept
```

pop up is normal webpage, so to click the close button use the following code, that pop up remain inside the iframe, so first we need to switch to that iframe and then you can click that close button

```
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait =10

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(id: '_bftn_iframe'))

driver.find_element(id: 'close').click
```

Comment: the popup dialog box doea not exist in the web site, that I was using to test and learn alert, I just updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Okay my day ia over , i will check tomorrow morning.